# spectrum.js flat colorpicker - position:fixed header

Tags: javascript, css, spectrumjs

I am using the spectrum.js flat colorpicker in a page that has a `position:fixed` header. The picker choices overlap the header while scrolling the page.

I have found [this issue](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/issues/152), but it seems to me that it applies to a picker contained into a fixed container, and not the other way round.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the F12 tools, I see that the color picker container has the `sp-container` class. In spectrum.css, the style defined for that class shows the following `z-index` property:

```
.sp-container {
    ...
    z-index: 9999994;
}
```

If you set `z-index: 9999995` (or more) for the fixed header, the color picker box will not overlap it.

```js
$("#inputColor").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
});
```

```css
#divHeader
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #CCC;
    background: #333;
    padding: 8px;
    z-index: 9999995;
}

#divContainer
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 1200px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/spectrum/1.8.0/spectrum.min.js"></script>
<div id="divHeader">Fixed header</div>
<div id="divContainer">
    <input id="inputColor" type="text" />
</div>
```